# Incorrect key file for table ,try to repair it?

Tags: mysql, unix

we are getting below error message in one of mysql server,from this messag i was not understood which table got corrupted .
we are using mysql 5.5.36 version for this server.

error message is:

```
140410 18:15:01 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql-5.5.36-linux2.6-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/var/tmp/#sql_4b24_1.MYI'; try to repair it
140410 18:15:01 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /pb2/build/sb_0-11244937-1389687661.25/mysql-5.5.36/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
140410 18:15:01 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql-5.5.36-linux2.6-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/var/tmp/#sql_4b24_8.MYI'; try to repair it
140410 18:15:01 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /pb2/build/sb_0-11244937-1389687661.25/mysql-5.5.36/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
140410 18:15:01 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql-5.5.36-linux2.6-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/var/tmp/#sql_4b24_11.MYI'; try to repair it
140410 18:15:01 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql-5.5.36-linux2.6-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/var/tmp/#sql_4b24_15.MYI'; try to repair it
140410 18:15:01 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /pb2/build/sb_0-11244937-1389687661.25/mysql-5.5.36/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
140410 18:15:01 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /pb2/build/sb_0-11244937-1389687661.25/mysql-5.5.36/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using auto-repair of all myisam table in start up using the variables in configuration files.

Refer the link:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_myisam-recover

Comment: i am using 5.5 version ,it not problem with the main tables ,it is is with the temp tables.